# Phonegap and ios - samples not working in simulator

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, ios-simulator, jqtouch

I started working with phonegap on ios. Ive been building the samples on the simulator and so far most of the samples that Ive tried build fine but usually arent fully functional for one reason or another. Does phonegap lose its functionality on the simulator? I have a devices to test on but I havent heard back from apple so I can provision them to develop on. With the way they keep people from developing on their devices its no wonder that android is killing it.

So has anyone else noticed this? Im using xcode 4.1 and the latest phonegap along with all the latest jquery/jqtouch stuff.

The usual problem with the demos on the simulator is that everything will load visually but none of the buttons will be touchable or some of the listviews wont load. Should I update my xcode? This mac stuff is killing me LOL.

EDIT: these are errors from me running the mapviewkit plugin demo

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance", referenced from:
  -[MapKitView setMapData:withDict:] in MapKit.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKMapView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MapKit.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PGAnnotation", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MapKit.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKPinAnnotationView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MapKit.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AsyncImageView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MapKit.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I decided to go ahead and update my xcode to the last 4.whatever to see if that makes any difference but from the reading I have done over the past two days I dont think it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap should run just fine in the simulator, only things you wont have access to are the camera, and locations are a bit funky, but other than that everything else is open to you.

Be sure you've got all the files in the correct places... try testing in a browser if possible to see if something isn't coming through...

Comment: Hey thanks for jumping in :) Ive tested the samples in a browser and easily got them running on android. Its just on the ios simulator its giving me a hard time. It seems like only some of the buttons links in ios version are active and I literally copied the source and just pasted it. Other times i just opened and ran the projects as is with the little bit of set up they required.

Comment: That is really strange... what version of phonegap are you using? have you installed it all correctly in xcode? I am just running through all the possible little problems that it could be, more than likely that's what it is...

Comment: Im using phongegap 1.4.1 and the rest is the latest and greatest jqstuff. Im starting to think that the simulator is just way to limited

Comment: Im now thinking that it has to be most of the tutorials and book material that Im using is just a little to old because Ive gone out and looked at some jquery/jtouch/jmobile sites and plugged them into phonegap and with just a tiny bit of alteration I got them working just fine. Im kind of bummed because I went out and bought some books and I ended up getting further by just looking at the source in the browser like I always do lol.